# Azurite not giving same results as Azure Storage Emulator when calling CreateCheckStatusResponse on Azure Durable Function

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, azure-durable-functions, azurite

I have an Azure Durable function as follows:

```
       [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
        HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        
        //code to get requestBodyContent from req hidden

        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MyOtherFunction", requestBodyContent);

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
     }
```

In the final line, the call to `CreateCheckStatusResponse` returns HTTP 202 as expected in the Azure Storage Emulator and the durable function executes with expected results.

When I run the same code within a Docker orchestration consisting of a function container and an Azurite container then the durable function still executes with expected results **but** `CreateCheckStatusResponse` returns a HTTP 500.

I would like to understand why the HTTP return code is behaving differently for the 2 different environments.

AppInsights doesn't show any issues.
Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationclient.createcheckstatusresponse?view=azure-dotnet) the method is not supposed to return 500 unless we specifically set a third boolean parameter.

Using .NETCore 3.1
Azure Functions V3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution - the problem was not Azurite, that is irrelevant in the OP.
The problem occurs when hosting a durable function within docker.
I came across the answer in [this post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/6).

Simply add the following config:

```
WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=localhost:30042
```